# Django static CSS file not linking to html document

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I am trying to link a css file to my html inside a django project but it does not seem to be linking.

base.html

```
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'myApp/styles.css' %}">
</head>
```

my folder structure

[image: folders]

Comment: There is one more folder named Static, that you should create or already presents. And place static files like JS, CSS, imgs in there. That's it says load static

Comment: where should i add the static folder in my folder structure

Comment: You can look into this django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: did you remember to configure the 'STATIC_URL' in settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

You static file(styles.css) should be in a static directory created in the root level.